# NoMethodError in StaticPages#home rails tutorial Michael Hartl chapter 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with Chapter 5, Section 1. I'm supposed to see a (dead) link on the home page, when I insert the code, but instead I get an error.

[image: Source Code]
[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Though I edited your question to show images, please avoid inserting images in general, insert plain code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 <%= link_to "simple app", "#" , :id=>"logo" %>
 <%= link_to "simple app", "#" , id: "logo" %>
```

Comment: Avoid using obsolete hashrocket syntax, use `id: 'logo'` instead.

Comment: found the error... inside ruby tags you must use a colon to assign a class or id, I used the equals sign like in normal HTML...

Comment: @mudasobwa: Just for the record, hashrockets are not obsolete. In fact they are still *required* for any non-symbol keys. For consistency, it is a valid choice to only use the hashrocket-style throughout your app.